# Can't connect to server

Tags: java, android, couchdb

I'm using [this](http://www.spikaapp.com/). I changed my base URL and database name, but when I try to sign up, I get the following error.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas? And if you can help and guide me towards what the base URL for couchDB would be great.

My current URL `public static final String BASE_URL                 ="http://10.0.2.2:5984/_utils/database.html?colourity";`

Comment: Logcat is first place to look for pointers.

Comment: If you can post your logcat will be better :)

Comment: Chack whether Have you declared Internet & necessary permissions to Menifest.

Answer (score 0):

That exception basically means that you're trying to speak a protocol to the server that it doesn't handle. For example, if you're trying to connect to a SOCKS4 proxy but the server is a HTML server, it will return you that response.

Basically, I'd try to debug a bit further. See via `Log.d()` what are you sending to the server, what is it issuing, what it might be answering, and see why the information you're sending to them is not correct.